# issues with python virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, django, macos

I am facing following 2 issues:

1. python command is not using the virtualenvwrapper python.
   After activating my virtual environment if I type python then the code still uses the native python libraries. I can easily install libraries etc with pip to my virtual environment but I cannot run any command using python.
   e.g. if I execute 
   **$ ./manage.py runserver**
   then it is fine and I can run a django server 
   but if I try 
   **$ python manage.py runserver**
   or even just
   **$ python**
   then it uses the native python libraries and that should not happen

This is while using iterm or terminal in osx. I have never faced this problem in any linux based os

2. While using any os (linux based or osx), the **workon** command doesn't work inside any shell script, while it works normally in a terminal

os: osx

Answer (score 0):

1. sounds like Python might be using the packages in site-packages, which means you should use the `--no-site-packages` flag when creating your virtualenv (although it seems like [this is the default](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption--no-site-packages) in the current version of virtualenv).
2. In order to access the `virtualenvwrapper` functions from a shell script, you will first need to `source` it: `$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` (the path might be different in your case).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but none of the above helped :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper from pip3.

```
pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

And then find where virtualenvwrapper.sh file is:

```
find / -name 'virualenvwrapper.sh'
```

I have mine in `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. But it seems that you have it in some different directory. So you must change below config to fit your needs.
And then in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
# Python3 virtualenv/venvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3' # This needs to be placed before the virtualenvwrapper command
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Projects
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh # your path to virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Let me know if it works :)